# Detect if PHP session exists

Tags: php, session

Facebook now offer subscriptions to users so you can get realtime updates on changes. If my app receives an update, I plan to store it in the database. I would also like to detect if their session exists. If it does then I could update the data in there too.

My session IDs are MD5(fb_id + secret) so I could easily edit their session. The question is how can I detect if the session exists.

Comment: Whose session do you mean? From where? Created by who?

Comment: What does "secret hashed" mean? If it's a proper hash, you can't get the fb_id back.

Comment: The users session, from my server, created by my server... sorry I thought it was a given

Comment: @Pablo if your server already creates a session, why do you need our help to detect whether it exists? I don't understand. You mean whether the user you're receiving an update for has a session on your end? Only your user management can tell that, can't it?

Comment: I agree with Pekka, why would you really need to know if the session exists? If you just always create a session in the same fashion, can't you just check if a certain variable stored in the session exists or not? It's a simple `isset($_SESSION['var'])` really.

Comment: As I understand it the sessions are deleted every x minutes of activity. So my question is how can I detect if there is a session active for that user. The only way I can think would be. session_id(md5(facebook_id+secret)); session_start(); if (!empty($_SESSION)) {//THERE IS A SESSION}

Comment: Ahh... so there is not better way to check if a session exists. Thanks

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If `$_SESSION` (or `$HTTP_SESSION_VARS` for PHP 4.0.6 or less) is used, use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check a variable is registered in `$_SESSION`.

```
isset($_SESSION['varname'])
```

Comment: I figured this would help other who stumble across this answer: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: As of April 2022, the link you provided is no longer working.

Answer (score 73):

I use a combined version:

```
if(session_id() == '' || !isset($_SESSION) || session_status() === PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    // session isn't started
    session_start();
}
```

Answer (score 35):

If you are on php 5.4+, it is cleaner to use [session_status()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php):

```
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) {
  echo 'Session is active';
}
```

- `PHP_SESSION_DISABLED` if sessions are disabled.
- `PHP_SESSION_NONE` if sessions are enabled, but none exists.
- `PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE` if sessions are enabled, and one exists.

Comment: Why using the comparison operator `==` instead of identity operator `===` ? Both return integers...

Comment: @micaball The `==` operator means "of equal value". The `===` operator means "of equal value and type".  We are only looking for true/false values in this comparison, so `==` is the better choice.

Comment: @micaball (Too) many php functions can return a mix of value types (A classic being `strpos()`). In that case it would effectively make sense to check the value type. `session_status()` always returns an `int`, so there is no need. :)

Comment: session_status() returns the numeric value of state so this needed a tweak for me of 
session_status() == 3

Comment: @ChrisLambrou The constants are defined as the numeric values. If you don't have a matching number to the listed constants, unless you are using a nonstandard or very old version of PHP (before 5.4), you may have something wrong with your setup that would explain why your constants are not defined properly.

Answer (score 2):

Which method is used to check if SESSION exists or not?
Answer:

```
isset($_SESSION['variable_name'])
```

Example:

```
isset($_SESSION['id'])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function is_session_started()
{
    if ( php_sapi_name() !== 'cli' ) {
        if ( version_compare(phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=') ) {
            return session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ? TRUE : FALSE;
        } else {
            return session_id() === '' ? FALSE : TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

// Example
if ( is_session_started() === FALSE ) session_start();
```

Comment: You should add a description to go with your code, even if brief. Posts of just code without explanations are frowned upon :)

Comment: To be fair, the code is pretty much self-explanatory. Thank you for the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

The original code is from [Sabry Suleiman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60805467/9583480).

Made it a bit prettier:

```php
function is_session_started() {

    if ( php_sapi_name() === 'cli' )
        return false;

    return version_compare( phpversion(), '5.4.0', '>=' )
        ? session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE
        : session_id() !== '';
}
```

First condition checks the [Server API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-sapi-name.php) in use. If Command Line Interface is used, the function returns false.

Then we return the boolean result depending on the [PHP version](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php) in use.

In ancient history you simply needed to check `session_id()`. If it's an empty string, then session is not started. Otherwise it is.

Since 5.4 to at least the current 8.0 the norm is to check `session_status()`. If it's not `PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE`, then either the session isn't started yet (`PHP_SESSION_NONE`) or sessions are not available altogether (`PHP_SESSION_DISABLED`).

Answer (score 0):

Shortest and simple answer

```
$_SESSION['variable_name']?? die;
```

its a simple way doing

```
if(isset($_session['variable'])){
      // do something
 }else{
     die;
 }
```