# Detect whether session_id(some-id) exists

Tags: php, sessionid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detect if PHP session exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538513/detect-if-php-session-exists)

The PHP manual does not seem to provide a means to check whether a given `session_id` exists. For example, `session_id()` has an optional `id` param, but that replaces the existing `id` as opposed to doing a lookup a la desired method: `session_id_exists(some-id)`

Why do I need to check whether a given `session_id` exists? Use case is a sports subscription service where password sharing has become a problem. On login I am storing the user's session id in DB and using that to compare against any other existing session id(s) attached to a given `userID`.

In order to implement, I need to check whether collected session ids exist in current session (the proof of password sharing being more than one user logged in at the same time).

I assume there's an easy way to achieve this...

Comment: There is no built in way to do this (AFAIK) - I think you would have to loop the files in the session data dir and check for the relevant file name. My immediate reaction was "you could do that with just the database" but now I think about it, I can't work out how...

Comment: I don't see how getting the session ID is going to help here. A session ID is generated upon a first visit for a session. Two users will "never" get the same session ID. What you can do, is check on every page view whether the session ID of the current user matches the session ID stored in the DB, and if not, log the user out.

Comment: Occurs to me that this might be a security feature; i.e not allowing a lookup against session data not related to current user's session. My intention is to, on discovering multiple users logged in on single account, log them all out (unset their sessions), lock the account and require password change

Comment: @CodeCaster, I'd prefer to avoid the every page view approach and overhead of DB lookup (although minimal). re: 2 users will never get the same session, that's exactly the point.  If DB session tracker contains 1 or more records attached to a single userID and stored sessionID is active, then we know the password has been leaked -- as the user attempting to login and the user(s) already logged in cannot be the same person (also tracking device and IP)

Comment: @CodeCaster I think you've slightly missed the point - what he needs to do is check if two currently existing sessions have the same user associated with them. So when a user logs in with a session ID this is stored, but if another user logs in with the same username but a different session ID, the password has been shared with someone. The point is to check whether the two session ID's exists concurrently - concievably a legit user would have two session IDs, but one would have expired. The case makes sense, although the approach is a little bit flawed (eg if a single user uses 2 browsers)

Comment: _"I'd prefer to avoid the every page view approach and overhead of DB lookup (although minimal)"_ Yeah and you rather scan all sessions to see whether they contain the current user's ID. Do you save one session ID per user, or do you have a table containing session ID's and user ID's?

Comment: @DaveRandom, yes, my original thought was to loop through session dir, but that presents security issues/hassles in implementing. I may just scrap the idea and go with a root cron job that audits user log, looking for simultaneous-ish (within 20 minutes) logins coming from different IPs on single account, and then lock/force-password-reset accordingly

Comment: For someone to be able to properly answer this question you need to show how you currently store your logins and sessions. You definetely should **not** scan all session files to see whether one of them contains the same user ID as the current session.

Comment: +1 @Dave. I would only take into account active sessions, as well as comparing DB stored IP against logging in user IP (so as to avoid locking a valid user's account in the event that they, for some reason, attempt to access login page directly when already logged in). The 2 browser issue is valid, more specifically, customer leaves work, gets in the car and while stuck in traffic, checks the site on their iPhone.

Comment: @CodeCaster, true, scanning entire session dir and grep'ing userID would be rather inefficient ;-) re: DB table: userID, sessID, ip, logTime. Something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, this has been a nice exploration of ways to prevent password sharing.

My gut reaction to tracking user activity on a per request basis (i.e. the 2 query solution proposed by @DaveRandom) was ahhhhh, no! As @CodeCaster points out, a likely case of premature optimization, but hey, we have a small (few thousand) but rabid user base that will be very click-happy with the start of hockey season and game results coming in.  The site has been running snappily for years, don't want to rock the boat, this is a paid service, so performance must be excellent.

OK, the solution:

The apache user has read/write access to the session files in the session directory. By recording session_id at time of login, we have the ingredients to lock down shared password accounts.  On successful login:

```
- Loop through stored session ids related to target account
- if /path/to/session-id-file not empty, increment login counter
- if login counter exceeds number of users allowed for a given plan:
- delete all session files related to target account
- lock the account and force a password reset
```

There is minimal overhead, the implementation is cake, problem solved.

Note: I had originally thought it was impossible to access the session directory files without creating a security loop; however, that is not the case (at least in my stock CentOS 5 setup). You cannot get a session_id not related to the current user's session, but you can store a given user's session id and *access the session file that stores their session* from any user's session (including blowing away the file).  The key is having the session id to lookup the corresponding /path/to/session-file

Answer (score 3):

How about you do something like this at the top of index.php

```
// Update current userid/session record with current timestamp
mysql_query("UPDATE sessions SET last_activity = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() WHERE user = '$username' AND sid = '".session_id()."'");
// Search for multiple records with timestamp in the last 20 minutes where user id is the same
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS current_sessions FROM sessions WHERE user = '$username' AND last_activity > '".date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - 1200)."'"));
if ($result['current_sessions'] > 1) {
  // handle duplicates here
}
```

You may not like this approach as it involves two DB queries at every page load, but it should work and would probably be more efficient than checking the session files.

Comment: Sure that would work nicely, just not preferred approach given the, imo, unnecessary db overhead.  If cron job can achieve the goal of locking down shared password accounts and incur zero overhead, then that is the route I'll explore first.

Comment: @virtualeyes not wanting to execute a single query sounds to me like premature optimization.

Comment: @CodeCaster, depends, how about a site that handles many concurrent users?  It boils down to running 2 extra queries for every single page request (@Dave's approach) to determine who is logged in under account X), or, at time of login, checking number of active sessions under account X. The latter solution incurs little to no overhead; I'll post it in awhile testing now...

Answer (score 0):

Following CodeCaster's comment:

Instead of checking PHP session IDs, you should, for each user connexion/disconnection & session expiration, maintain a list of currently connected users (along with connection time, IP etc. maybe), for example in a DB table.

Thus you will be able to detect multiple connections with a single account.

You can as well try to create a small script looping over all session files (if you use the default storage), use an 'unserialize()' on it and check if several session files have the same user identifiers (provided that you store them into `$_SESSION`)

**EDIT**: since this should be done for each user connection, the DB table approach (like what CodeCaster suggests) seems better.

Comment: Again, while the overhead is not large, querying on every single page request for multiple users logged in under a single account is inefficient. My inclination now is to run an early AM root cron job that audits user log, checking for simultaneous logins during the day, and locking accounts accordingly (along with sending a warning email). Zero overhead, and achieves goal of locking out shared password accounts.

Comment: @virtualeyes even if you are going to do it with a cronjob, you still need to store the times/session ids at which a user had activity, which involves writing to a file or database on every page load anyway - there is no way around that because PHP will delete the expired session files, so there will be no data to check at early AM.

Comment: @virtualeyes Actually, you could try setting `session.gc_probability` to `0` in all your pages, and then manually do the garbage collection with your cronjob, but I don;t recommend that unless the server is dedicated to that site and only that site - even then it's risky.

Comment: @Dave, not true, on login I store userID, ip, logTime, browser, etc. Otherwise, for page-to-page requests I do nothing.  The audit trail is there in the log table.  For shared password accounts it's quite clear just looking at the logs (near same time login but different IPs & different browsers)

Comment: @virtualeyes But it's not "logged in within x time" you're bothered about, it's "was active within x time". If I log in at 9am, and stay logged in all day, and someone else logs in with the same details at 4pm, just checking the login time won't catch the fact that 2 users were logged in with the same username at the same time, because the login times were 7 hours apart... hence, you need to log activity, not logins

Comment: @Dave I agree, but in this particular case I don't ;-) There is no logged in all day, you would have to perform a page click every 20 minutes (session expire time), which is not realistic given that users login to see if a new article has been posted, on average 1 or 2 articles per day. In other words, you would have to be fairly insane to keep your session active all day. What is abundantly clear looking in the log is that geographically disparate users (based on ip) are logging into the site 10, 20 minutes apart, a clear sign of password sharing.

Answer (score 0):

You should create your own *Session State* implementation that offers an interface for the action(s) you need to have for your use-case.

```
class SessionState
{
    public function idExists($id)
    {
        $gateway = new SessionGateway();
        $result = $gateways->searchById($id);
        # ... 
    }
}
```

If you have implemented the details, you can just use the object(s) within your application.

Comment: That's fairly sparse, I assume by session state implementation you mean store session state in DB in place of php default in-memory implementation? Not looking to devote my life to this project, a quick & dirty-ish solution will suffice (@DaveRandom's topping the list at present), php is unpleasant enough to revisit, let alone the thought of doing actual work in it again ;-)

Comment: Lolz, as sparse it is, as fast it is to code. Anyway, that's totally independent to the storage layer you choose. The gateway is taking care of that, just do whatever you need to do and done. If you change later on to RDBMS based storage against file database storage, do so. If you need a parser for session files, checkout the [Serialized](https://github.com/ktomk/Serialized) library.

Comment: the problem is, I have no idea what you are talking about, nor does anyone else based on lack of comments/upvotes.  Given your heavy SO ranking, however, it's clear that you know what you are talking about ;-) Therefore, by "fairly sparse" I meant, would you care to elaborate on what you mean by, for example "new SessionGateway()"? In other words, the SessionState class is not yet triggering a eureka moment, although it might with a bit more detail and/or link to an example implementation.  thanks...

Comment: @virtualeyes: Okay, forget about the patterns, those are more or less to encapsulate what varies in your situation and should make it easy for your application to deal with the overall issue.

Comment: @virtualeyes: But you're more tight to a bare problem: You want the userid to be the session id. You can encrypt it with a secret and then use it as `session_id` (as you already know, you can set it). Next to that store the IP inside the session. If a user re-uses the session with a different IP trigger the password reset. You can do this easily with an additional session (using two sessions sequentially), the current one and the new userid-one. Just don't use cookies for the new one so it stays private. Filter session id's for the public one that those can't inject the user-session-id.

Comment: +1 @hakre, clever, had not thought about setting encrypted session id. Running queries every single request to track user activity is simply inefficient, session state already reveals who is logged in under a given account; getting at said state is another matter, one best suited to a root cron job, imo.  Run every 10 minutes, cron can batch process logged in users, find shared passwords; drop the hammer (lock account) and (since root has full access to session dir) blow away illegal user sessions, wreaking wonderous wtf-happend havok ;-)