# php check if session_id is same

Tags: php, session

I want to update the db field if session_id is new. If session_id is same I don’t want to update mysql table.
How do I check if session_id is same?

```
session_start();
session_id();
if(HOW DO I CHECK IF SESSION_ID IS SAME)
{
$count_query = "UPDATE ".TBL_JGL_VISIT." SET no_of_visit = no_of_visit + 1 WHERE id = '1'";
mysql_query($count_query, $CN);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect whether session\_id(some-id) exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166676/detect-whether-session-idsome-id-exists)

Comment: Since you already have the previous session id stored in the db, get it, and compare it to the one currently available?

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php
session_id() returns a string

```
$sess_id = session_id();
```

You should store this string in database and check if this particular string has already been recorded in your database.

Beware of sessions length ;-p It could play tricks on you depending on what you try to accomplish with this.

Answer (score 0):

You just need a query to SELECT the session row from the database beforehand and

```
if ($row_session == session_id()){
//do sth
}
```