# How can you check if a PHP session exists?

Tags: php, session

Just wondering how to check if a PHP session exists... My understanding is that no matter what, if I am using sessions, I have to start my files with session_start() to even access the session, even if I know it already exists.

I've read to user session_id() to find out if a session exists, but since I have to use session_start() before calling session_id(), and session_start() will create a new ID if there isn't a session, how can I possible check if a session exists?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538513/detect-if-php-session-exists

Comment: A session exists when you call session_start(), but is meaningless unless you use it for something. Maybe if you explain a bit further what you're trying to achieve, we might help you.

Comment: My problem is I'm making this trivial game for a school project, and if there are session variables set, I know I'm in a later round of the game. If there are no session variables set, I know it's the first round and have to do some extra work. As of now I'm just checking if one of the session variables is set, but it doesn't feel like the most elegant solution.

Comment: Well, you can use a var like $_SERVER['gameHasStarted'] which defaults to false unless the user performs some action and that is reset when the user ends the game. (when you destroy the session).

Comment: Yeah that's what I've ended up doing, seems to be the best way to go. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In PHP versions prior to 5.4, you can just the [`session_id()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php) function:

```
$has_session = session_id() !== '';
```

In PHP version 5.4+, you can use [`session_status()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-status.php):

```
$has_session = session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE;
```

Comment: After `session_start()`, `isset($_SESSION)` is always `TRUE`. Also the `session_status()` is not what the OP asked for.

Comment: I suggest you read the question again. Your answer is just not an answer at all in context of the question. The only check you do is to check whether `session_start()` has been called already or not.

Comment: @traxn: The success of the function call was implicated. The other part you say is right, but has been answered before in a different question. That is also useful for taking care of session timeouts (last time of activity in a session and tracking it).

Comment: he explicitly said he didn't want to call `session_start` first, so "success of the function call" to `session_start` is definitely not a given.

Comment: OP asks himself - at least that is how I understand the question - how to detect if a session is new or did exist while having the problem that *after* calling (successfully) `session_start()`, the `$_SESSION` array is set (and additionally in the light of this answer `session_status()` is active) and it's not possible to differ if the session *has just been created* -or- *is continuing*.

Comment: that's not what he asked. but in any case, i addressed that in my comment about checking for the existence of a value in the $_SESSION array.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18691/discussion-between-hakre-and-traxn)

Comment: This does not answer the question. ARW is asking how to tell if a session has previously been started on a previous visit to the site not if a session has been started on this visit to the site.

Answer (score 18):

```
isset($_SESSION)
```

That should be it. If you wanna check if a single session variable exists, use `if(isset($_SESSION['variablename']))`.

Answer (score 13):

I find it best many times (depends on the nature of the application) to simply test to see if a session cookie is set in the client:

```
<?php

if (isset($_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"])) {
    echo "active";
} else {
    echo "don't see one";
}

?>
```

Of course, replace the default session name "PHPSESSID" with any custom one you are using.

Comment: Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Agree to this solution as really working one. I ran into exactly the same problem (PHP 7.1.8): 
**session_id()**: Empty on destroyed session but also empty even tough a session exists (just not yet resumed by start_session) / 
**session_status()**: Showing 1 (PHP_SESSION_NONE) on destroyed session but also showing 1 even tough a session exists (just not yet resumed by start_session)
All over: I couldn't find a PHP function that could differ between "No session active" and "a session exists but not yet started".

Comment: Perfect solution

Answer (score 7):

In PHP there is something called the session name. The name is co-related to the cookie that will be being set *if* the session was already started.

So you can check the `$_COOKIE` array if there is a session cookie available. Cookies are normally the preferred form to interchange the session id for the session name with the browser.

If a cookie already exists this means that a PHP session was started earlier. If not, then `session_start()` will create a new session id and session.

A second way to check for that is to [check the outgoing headers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.headers-list.php) if the cookie for the session is set there. It will be set if it's a new session. Or if the session id changed.

Comment: + For Explanation  ..... just curios .. i can see any cookies on `PHP/5.3.8` information after running http://pastebin.com/Bc86FFmh ?? Any Ideas

Comment: @traxn: After you have obtained the sessionid from cookie, you check against the session store. You can't do earlier. If the session store has an entry for the session id, the session - by definition - exists.

Comment: @traxn: Overridden or not - the sesison store is the session store. Don't run away only because you can configure something.

Comment: @Baba: Double check, it is likely that the session cookie was already set if not in the outgoing headers. Set to a new `session_name()` if you want to provoke a new session.

Comment: @traxn: You check the file existence and it's content. After session_start the contents can be compared with `$_SESSION`. If the GC did kick in in between, `$_SESSION` would not match with the snapshot of the store. Hence you know about that GC worked. No problem to deal with that case. Normally you have a more optimized session store and take care of GC yourself so this is even more fluent. Anyway, I have no clue what you try to proof here. Sounds a bit like fighting windmills.

Comment: @traxn: No, that race-condition is shielded by PHP then. From the time you call `session_start()`.

Comment: @hakre i see the issue here i can see it now only with the code : http://pastebin.com/2fPWvwmJ

Comment: By calling `session_name("WxebsiteID" . mt_rand());` i was able to see sent header information for `Set-Cookie:` ... not sure if this is a good way to validate session since it only shows once

Comment: Exactly, it will only show once, for that once when `session_start()` creates a *new* session. The enforcing of a new name only saved you from cleaning up your browser-cookies.

Comment: No, before calling session_start. Because after session_start the file is locked. That's how PHP shields that. The file is locked.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18691/discussion-between-hakre-and-traxn)

Answer (score 3):

**isset($_SESSION)** isn't sufficient because if a session has been created and destroyed (with `session_destroy()`) in the same execution, **isset($_SESSION)** will return **true**. And this situation may happen without your knowing about it when a 3rd party code is used. `session_id()` correctly returns an empty string, though, and can be called prior to `session_start()`.

Answer (score 1):

Check if session exists before calling session_start()

```
if(!isset($_SESSION))session_start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call session_id before session_start. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php - read the id param

Comment: Caution: Only to set the new session ID.

Answer (score 0):

I've always simply used

```
if (@session_id() == "") @session_start();
```

Hasn't failed me yet.

Been quite a long time using this.

*NOTE*: `@` simply suppresses warnings.

Comment: **Never** use `@` to silence issues.

Comment: I don't think that this answers the original question asked.

Answer (score 0):

Store the `session_id` in `$_SESSION` and check against it.

First time

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['id'] = session_id();
```

Starts a session and stores the randomly given session id.

Next time

```
session_start();
$valid_session = isset($_SESSION['id']) ? $_SESSION['id'] === session_id() : FALSE;
if (!$valid_session) {
   header('Location: login.php');
   exit();
}
```

Starts a session, checks if the current session id and the stored session id are identical (with the ternary ? as replacement for the non-existing short circuit AND in php). If not, asks for login again.

Comment: The whole idea was not calling session_start() again to check, since this creates a new session no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

switch off the error reporting if noting is working in your php version put top on your php code

`error_reporting(0);`

Answer (score -1):

I solved this three years ago, but I inadvertently erased the file from my computer.

it went like this.  3 pages that the user had to visit in the order I wanted.

1) top of each php page 
  `enter code here`session start();`enter code here`
2) first page:
  a) `enter code here`$_session["timepage1"] = a php date function; time() simple to use
  b) `enter code here`$_session["timepage2"]= $_session["timepage1"];
  b) `enter code here`$_session["timepage3"]=$_session["timepage1"];
3) second page:
    a) `enter code here`$_session["timepage2"] = a php date function; time() simple to use
    b) `enter code here`$_session["timepage3"]= $_session["timepage3"];
 3) third page:
    a) `enter code here`$_session["timepage3"] = a php date function; time() simple to use

the logic:
 if timepage3 less than timepage3 on page 2
{the user has gone to page 3 before page 2 do something}

if timepage2 on page 2 less than timepage1 
{the user may be trying to hack page two we want them on page 1 do something}

timepage1 should never equal timepage2 or timepage3 on any page except page1 because if it is not greater on pages two or three the user may be trying to hack "do something"

you can do complex things with simple arithmetic with the 3 timepage1-2-3 variables. you can either redirect or send a message to say please go to page 2. you can also tell if user skipped page 2. then send back to page 2 or page one, but best security feature is say nothing just redirect back to page1.

if you `enter code here`echo time(); on every page, during testing, you will see the last 3 digits going up if you visit in the correct order.