# Defining session start in if block causing the session to create again on page refresh

Tags: php

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['SessData'])) {
    session_name('sess1');
    session_start();

    echo '----- In IF Condition -----';
    print_r($_SESSION['SessData']['Tracker']['Source']);
}
else {
    echo '----- In ELSE Condition -----';
    print_r($_SESSION['SessData']['Tracker']['Source']);
}
```

When executing the code its only going in the IF condition and not the else condition. Whats the reason behind it?

Comment: start session on top of your page just after `<?php` tag and your problem will resolved

Comment: But what's the reason behind that? First time in IF condition the session will be created so next time on page refresh it should come in else statement. Isn't it? Correct me on this if I'm wrong...

Comment: Check this link:-http://www.thecreativedev.com/session-start-at-the-top-of-the-page/

Comment: Read the link but it states no print or echo statements before session_start or setcookie and in my code the echo statement is after session_start.

Comment: You can't print a session value without a started session.  It makes the else part redundant.  Unless you are starting the session somewhere else previously.

Comment: @Progrock Okay assume 1st time the if condition becomes true and the session starts. Then I refresh my page and since the session is not already started so it will come in else part. Right?

Comment: Why don't you understand that you can not apply anything (conditions, assignment, iteration etc)on session variables till you not started session in beginning. So your code will give some undefined index type error always

Comment: When you refresh your page you will be back to square one.  Whenever you need to refer to a session, you have to use session_start().

Comment: @Progrock if I put it at the top of the page and refresh page every time will result in the session_start() statement being executed everytime.

Comment: yes and then only you can apply anything on session, session variables and values are not accessible till you are not starting session

Comment: @A-2-A see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114185/how-can-you-check-if-a-php-session-exists

Comment: @A-2-A the solution in the above link is checking the session in the same way as I.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6249707/check-if-php-session-has-already-started check the link, but the solution here depends upon your PHP version..

Comment: You are checking session data and either it have some value or not you can not access it till you not start the session. starting the session will not affect session variables an there values

Comment: @ameenulla0007 thanks man! You saved my day.

Comment: you are always welcome.. :) @SURFER-TM

Answer (score 0):

The working code is as follows:

```
if(phpversion()  < '5.4.0') {
    if(session_id() == '') {
        session_name('sess1');
        session_start();
        echo 'here1';
    }
    else {}
}
else if(phpversion()  >= '5.4.0') {
    if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_name('sess1');
        session_start();
        echo 'here2';
    }
    else {}
}


if(!isset($_SESSION['SessData'])) {
    echo '----- In IF Condition -----';
    print_r($_SESSION['SessData']['Tracker']['Source']);
    echo '<br />';
    echo session_id();
}
else {
    echo '----- In ELSE Condition -----';
    print_r($_SESSION['SessData']['Tracker']['Source']);
    echo '<br />';
    echo session_id();
}
```