# Session is saved but the page kick me out

Tags: php, session

I tried to check if the session is still exist, if it doesnt, it will kick me out from the page.

```
session_start();
if (empty($_SESSION['locationed']))
    {
         header("Location: http://exit.php");
         die();
    }
```

The code above always kick me out of the page.

When I delete the code above and echo the session:

```
   $locationed=$_SESSION['locationed'];

   <?php echo $locationed; ?>
```

It echos my session of location.

What is wrong? Help please.

Comment: Paste code where you set $_SESSION['locationed']

Comment: what are the contents of that var?

Comment: Check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538513/detect-if-php-session-exists. You should check if the session is `isset`.

Comment: mark it as answered if it answers your question

Answer (score 2):

try isset rather than empty.

```
if (!isset($_SESSION))
    {
         header("Location: http://exit.php");
         die();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go  .

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['locationed'])) {
     header("Location: http://exit.php");
     die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['locationed']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try those combinations,

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['locationed']) && empty($_SESSION['locationed'])) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["locationed"]) || empty($_SESSION['locationed']))
{
  header("Location: http://exit.php");
  die();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
session_start();
$_SESSION['locationed']="1234";
echo $_SESSION['locationed']; //if echo something means getting something on that
if($_SESSION['locationed'] =='' && !isset($_SESSION['locationed']))
    {
         header("Location: http://exit.php");
         die();
    }
```