# restrict access to file uploaded in image folder. PHP

Tags: php

I have to give restriction to the file uploaded by  user.

SHOW only `session` is set .

folder structure is like this

```
image/user1/all files uploaded by user1
image/user2/all files uploaded by user2
image/user3/all files uploaded by user3
```

so when above path open in browser url like

```
mywebsite.com/image/user1/file1.jpg
mywebsite.com/image/user1/file1.pdf
```

so it will be visible to everyone I want to give restriction to it.

I have tried like this (using `chmode`)
for image folder i have set permission as `600`

```
<?php chmod("image",0777);?>
```

but how to restrict it from browser show only when perticular session is set

Comment: possible duplicate, but anyway, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538513/detect-if-php-session-exists

Comment: @PHClaus this is not what i want to acheive

Comment: I was referring to the part where it explains how to check whether or not a given session is set. Never mind.