# Session not starting in PHP 7.4 but the same code works in PHP 7.1

Tags: php, session-variables

backend.php file : where following session variables are being set

```
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
    $_SESSION['user_email'] = $user_email;
```

Next : As I can verify in the directory /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74 the session files are getting created. After this the session suppose to be read and understood by the website frontend index.php file and for that below is the index.php code

```
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['user_email'])){

update session variable e.g., 
$user_email = $_SESSION['user_email'];

}else{
    echo "session not set"; 
}
```

but somehow the session_start() or if(isset($_SESSION['user_email'])) is not functioning hence the flow always go to else condition and it ends with "session not set"

Note: The php.ini file contains session.save_path = "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74"

Please suggest!

Comment: Make sure the folder is writable by apache, I don't know what OS you are using but for centOS, it would be chown -R apache:apache /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74

Comment: the user session is being set by the backend file as I can see that there are session files getting created in the directory: /var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php74               session file: sess_33xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx542 . So, folder is certainly writable by apache. Problem is index.php whose code I wrote in my main question and I guess it's the session_start() which is the problem ?

Comment: you have to add the portion of the code where you define the value of $_SESSION['user_email'] ;)

Comment: You probably have 2 different php.ini files for the different php versions. Check any lines that contain the word "session", especially "lazy_write"

Answer (score 1):

you must have to start session before setting initial value for session e.g:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id;
$_SESSION['user_email'] = $user_email;
```

and then you can read or edit session values:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_email'])){

echo "session is set";

}else{
    echo "session not set"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Test session id

```
if(!empty(session_id()){
    echo "Booo raczki ..."
}
```

And

```
if(!empty($_SESSION['user_email'])){
   echo "Works ...."
}
```

[Detect if PHP session exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538513/detect-if-php-session-exists)