# Error inserting comment in Unity whit C# & PHP

Tags: c#, php, unity-game-engine

I need help with an insert in Unity with php and c#.
My idea is that a user can make one or more comments, and allow to see who made said comment. For this I have two tables, one for users and another for opinions.

The PHP script I have it like this:

```
<?php
session_start();

include("config.php"); //archivo de conexion a base de datos
include("index.php");  

if(isset($_POST["newComentarioPaisaje"])){
    $comentario = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["newComentarioPaisaje"]);
    //$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_POST["newAccountUsername"]);
//validar que no este vacio para enviar
if($comentario != "" ){
        mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO opiniones (comentario,id) VALUES ('$comentario','$id_user')");
        echo "Registro de comentario exitoso!";

            
}else{
    echo "No puede enviar un comentario vacío!";
}
}
```

and the c # like this:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class comentarioPaisaje : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    public string baseUrl = "http://192.168.100.3/ramus/InsertPaisaje.php"; //server donde esta la bd/carpeta que contiene el archivo de conexion a db
    

    public InputField ComentarioPaisaje;
    public Text infopaisaje;
    
    
    public void CommentRegister()
    {
        string paiComentario = ComentarioPaisaje.text;
        StartCoroutine(RegisterNewComentario(paiComentario));

        
    }
    
    IEnumerator RegisterNewComentario(string paiComentario)
    {
        WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
        form.AddField("newComentarioPaisaje", paiComentario);
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Post(baseUrl, form))
        {
            www.downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer();
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
 
            if (www.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                string responseText = www.downloadHandler.text;
                Debug.Log("" + responseText); //la respuesta que se le da al usuario
                infopaisaje.text = "" + responseText; //la respuesta que se le da al usuario
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

The error that I get in unity:

**Notice**:  session_start(): Ignoring session_start() because a session is already active in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ramus\index.php** on line **3**
Error :(
**Warning**:  Undefined variable $id_user in **C:\xampp\htdocs\ramus\InsertPaisaje.php** on line **13**
Registro de comentario exitoso!

Comment: Its right. You never define id_user. This has nothing to do with unity or c#

Answer (score 0):

The first message **NOTICE** is because you have already a session and try to create a new one with `session_start()`. `session_destroy()` or `session_unset()` at the beginning of PHP code should avoid that error. But you can also check if a session already exists, [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538513/detect-if-php-session-exists).

About the second message **WARNING**, it is because you are not declaring the variable $id_user. So it doesn't exist but you try to access to it.

[session_destroy()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)

[session_unset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-unset.php)